# Dynamically Loading Plugin Configuration Files in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakedc, cakephp-3.4

Question: How do I load a configuration file from a Plugin/config Directory?

Demo Project: https://github.com/CakePHPKitchen/CakeDC-Users-Permissions-Example

I am using CakeDC/users plugin and it has a permissions.php file that it loads the RBAC permissions from. From what I can tell, it either loads the default permissions file that is in the user plugin's config folder OR it loads the permissions.php file from the app/config folder.

Now for my app skeleton I have a bunch of permissions in the app/config/permissions.php, however, I do not want to modify that file as I will be doing git pulls from the upstream repo and I would like to avoid conflicts.

So what I would like to do is, in the app skeleton bootstrap

I would like to

```
foreach(Plugin::loaded() as $plugin) {

     $path = Plugin::path($plugin) . 'config/permissions.php';

     if(file_exists($path)) {

        Configure::load($path, 'default', true);
     }
}
```

But I am getting the following error....

```
 Error: The application is trying to load a file from the /Users/jlroberts/Projects/JeffreyLRobertsCom/CakePHPKitchen/PluginDemos/plugins/SharpAgent/config/permissions plugin. 

 Make sure your plugin /Users/jlroberts/Projects/JeffreyLRobertsCom/CakePHPKitchen/PluginDemos/plugins/SharpAgent/config/permissions is in the /Users/jlroberts/Projects/JeffreyLRobertsCom/CakePHPKitchen/PluginDemos/plugins/ directory and was loaded.
```

Any ideas on how I can load the permissions.php file from the Plugin/config directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED: You can load permissions.php file from the Plugin as it is doing now, but change the contents of permissions.php to preserve existing permissions defined in configuration, for example:

config/permissions.php

```
$permissions = [
    // add your app permissions here
    [
        // ...
    ],
];

// there are more permissions in this config key, defined across your plugins
$morePermissions = \Cake\Core\Configure::read('MyPermissions');
$allPerms = array_merge($permissions, $morePermissions);

return ['CakeDC/Auth.permissions' => $allPerms];
```

Then inside each plugin you could have:

YOUR_PLUGIN/config/bootstrap.php

```
$permissions = \Cake\Core\Configure::read('MyPermissions');
$someMorePermissions = [
    [
        // permissions injected into the app from this plugin
    ]
];

$permissions = array_merge((array)$permissions, $someMorePermissions);
\Cake\Core\Configure::write('MyPermissions', $permissions);
```

Allowing each plugin to dynamically inject/manage permissions into the app.

I've created a c9.io environment with this code here https://ide.c9.io/steinkel/users-35-custom-permissions

Comment: I created a demo project, it has the code you recommended in the Example Plugin bootstrap.php... https://github.com/CakePHPKitchen/CakeDC-Users-Permissions-Example

Comment: The permissions haven't been added to the config yet when the plugin bootstrap loads, and if I set the permissions for the plugin in the bootstrap, they eventually get overwritten...

Comment: It appears to me that the permissions.php file doesn't get loaded until the constructor of SimpleRbacAuthorize.php in CakeDC/auth is fired... Seems like to me, for what you are saying to work, it needs to be loaded from a bootstrap of either CakeDC/auth or CakeDC/users

Comment: Took me a month before I got back to this, looks great, thank you so much!